# Why do I need to catch a close() exception in BufferedReader but not in PrintWriter?

Tags: java

I have a simple file read and write function.

```
private void WriteToFile(String filename, String val) {
    PrintWriter outStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        outStream = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
        outStream.print(val);
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (outStream != null) {
            outStream.close();
        }
    }
}

private String ReadFile(String filename) {
    String output = "";
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader(filename);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        output = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

When building I get:

```
unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            br.close();
                    ^
```

Why do I need to catch br.close but it doesn't complain about WriteToFile's close()?

Comment: try moving `br.close()` to a `finally` block

Comment: That's just how the ancient `PrintWriter` is designed. No one of its methods throws an `IOException`. Use `FileWriter` instead to have them.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the read. Is there an 'equivalent' reader whose close method doesn't throw an exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from the source code of java.io.PrintWriter:

```
public void close() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (out == null)
                return;
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

The IOException was eaten up within the close() method in PrintWriter

From source code of java.io.BufferedReader:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        cb = null;
    }
}
```

BufferedReader throws the IOException.

That should answer your question.

Comment: Makes sense. I just put another try-catch in a finally block, but that seems convoluted. Is there something similar to BufferedReader whose close function catches its own exception?

Comment: java.util.Scanner is the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

*Why do I need to catch br.close but it doesn't complain about WriteToFile's close()?*

You can check the Java Docs for this. The `close()` method for [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close%28%29) :

```
public void close()
           throws IOException
```

And the `close()` method for [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#close%28%29) :

```
public void close()
```

That answer's your question as to why JVM doesn't complain. Because it is clear from the method signatures;

Answer (score 2):

`PrinterWriter.close()` doesn't throw any Exception. 
If you call `fos.close()`, it will ask you to catch/throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

In the PrintWriter.java. The exception is caught and handled. So you needn't catch it while using.

Java Source:

```
 public void close() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (out == null)
                    return;
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
            trouble = true;
        }
    }
```

But in BufferedReader the exception is thrown. So you have to catch it when using.

Java Source:

```
  public void close() throws IOException {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (in == null)
                    return;
                in.close();
                in = null;
                cb = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's not the reason. The reason is that the method isn't declared to throw IException.